# Adding specific keys to 'template'

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an xml file which I need to transform into a smaller template xml which was formated into a dict with keys and empty values while also ignoring some of the data,I've made the template with the the keys I am searching for in the xml and converted the xml into a dict also but now I'm stuck trying to dump the data into it,any ideas on how it could be accomplished?thank you!

```
<useless>no use<\useless>
<key1>1<\key1>
 <key1_1>11<\key1_1>
 <key1_2>12<\key1_2>
  <key1_2_1>121<\key1_2_1>
```

Comment: I can't tell what you mean.  Are you just trying to rewrite the XML file without those tags?  What have you already tried?

Comment: Yes,basically just to rewrite the xml while only referring to certain tags,I have a working code with for inside for loops but I need to do the same with an external template, just wondering if it's possible in python

Comment: Also, what is your current code?

Comment: Is the template just more XML?  If so, how is it different from what you already have?